# BATCH: If "String" equals "="

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file that I want to check that a string does not contain a "=" symbol. I am finding it difficult to figure out how to set "=" to a variable in BATCH script.I have tried set MDSSTR=%%= and ="%%=" to no avail

An example of what I am trying to do is below:

```
//example
set MDSStr="="
set mdsvar="Hello=World" 
if NOT %mdsvar% == %MDSStr% ( Do Something)
```

Does anyone know how to make a "=" symbol become a string? Thank you in advance.

Comment: but the code you've posted works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "MDSStr=="
set "mdsvar=Hello=World" 
set "mdsvar2==Hello World" 
set "mdsvar3=Hello World=" 
set "mdsvar4=Hello=====World" 
set "mdsvar5======Hello World" 
set "mdsvar6=Hello World=====" 
set "mdsvar7=Hello World" 

SET mds
ECHO --------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsstr%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar2%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar3%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar4%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar5%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar6%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("x%mdsvar7%x") DO IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO no "=") ELSE (ECHO "=" found)

GOTO :EOF
```

This demonstrates a method of detecting the presence of `=` in a string.

the variables starting `mds` are set up to various combinations of characters containing `=` - some at the start, some at the end, some in the middle. The very last variable is set to **not** contain `=`.

The values set in the `mds` variables are then shown and each is processed for a report.

Unfortunately, you seem to explain **how** you want to do something, but not **what** it is that you want to do. Perhaps it's simply `find out whether the string contains "="`, but that seems to be overshadowed by the quest to have a variable with value <kbd>=</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need escape `=`. Try to do it so `^=`.

Answer (score 0):

To put an "=" in a string do this:

```
set "MDSStr=="
```

Echo your string and pipe the output to the find command to find display only lines that do not contain the find string (=) like this:

```
set "MDSStr=="
set mdsvar="Hello=World" 
echo(%mdsvar% | find /v "%MDSStr%"
```